# Escape characters in sed transliterate

Tags: sed, freebsd, string, macos, tr

I want to use `sed`'s transliterate (`y///`) to replace one set of characters by another.

I would expect this to work just as well as using the `tr` program.

```
$ echo '[]{}abc' | tr '[ab}' 'gefh' 
g]{hefc
```

However, when I go to perform this same operation with sed, I see the following error:

```
$ echo '[]{}abc' | sed 'y/[ab}/gefh/' 
sed: 1: "y/[ab}/gefh/": unbalanced brackets ([])
```

This makes some sense, as I expect to need to escape the `[` character. However, when I do try and escape that, I receive the following, different error:

```
$ echo '[]{}abc' | sed 'y/\[ab}/gefh/' 
sed: 1: "y/\[ab}/gefh/": transform strings are not the same length
```

My current work-around is to either (1) just use `tr` or (2) insert a "dummy character" in the right-hand side of the transliteration whose job is to do nothing but match the escape character.

```
$ echo '[]{}abc' | sed 'y/\[ab}/_gefh/' 
g]{hefc
```

This is however unsatisfying and suspicious. It's also not very safe, e.g. when `\` is in the input string.

```
$ echo '[]{}abc\' | sed 'y/\[ab}/_gefh/' 
g]{hefc_
```

What's the correct way to escape a character in a sed transliteration without sed treating the escape character itself a part of the translation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are on macOS (the only system whose native `sed` I can get to display this issue, although I haven't checked on FreeBSD whence macOS's `sed` comes):

```bsh
$ echo '[]{}abc' | sed 'y/[ab}/gefh/'
sed: 1: "y/[ab}/gefh/": unbalanced brackets ([])
```

```bsh
$ echo '[]{}abc' | sed 'y/\[ab}/gefh/'
sed: 1: "y/\[ab}/gefh/": transform strings are not the same length
```

```bsh
$ echo '[]{}abc' | sed 'y/\[ab}/\gefh/'
g]{hefc
```

So, *one* solution is to

1. Escape the `[` in the first string to avoid having an unbalanced bracket, and
2. Make the two strings equal length by adding a "no-op" backslash to the second string too.

Or,

- You could also enclose both strings in `[...]`, which, upon reflection, may be the safest way to deal with this as it can be done in a mechanical manner without caring about where in the string the `[` is located:

  ```bsh
  $ echo '[]{}abc' | sed 'y/[[ab}]/[gefh]/'
  g]{hefc
  ```
- Or install GNU `sed` via e.g. Homebrew on macOS, or FreeBSD's package system, and use that.

I would treat this as a bug in this `sed` implementation.

Comment: FreeBSD 11.2 has the same bug. BusyBox 1.30.1 has a similar bug. At a guess, they reuse code from parsing character sets in regular expressions, and they parse character classes (things like `[:alnum:]`), even though they don't use the result of that parsing (correctly: `y/[:alnum:]/…/` is supposed to replace the characters `:almnu[]`, not alphanumerical characters).

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is the correct way: `[` is always supposed to be an ordinary character in sed `y///`. This is different from `tr` where `[` can be part of a character class like `[:alpha:]`.

Unfortunately, several implementations of sed evidently have a bug that causes them to try to parse balanced brackets in sed. I've observed the bug you describe with FreeBSD 11.2 and with BusyBox 1.30.1.

Using backslashes is tricky: the behavior of backslash+character is not [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/sed.html) except when the character is `\`, `n` or the delimiter. So while you can perhaps use it to work around the bug in your specific implementation, the resulting code probably won't work with another implementation.

A portable workaround is to temporarily swap `[` with some other character that you don't want to change, and in the same replacement translate `]` to itself. To avoid likely possible buggy parses, this character shouldn't be `]`, `^` or `:`. When you're doing the swap, you'll need to construct a string with balanced brackets and with something between them. FreeBSD doesn't like `[]` in the replacement either; an easy way to work around this is to put an extra character before the `]`. For example, I'll use `B` as the temporary `[`.

```
y/[B_]/B[_]/; y/Bab}/gefh/; y/[B_]/B[_]/
```